# Play 2.5 module sbt compile

Tags: java, testing, playframework, sbt, cucumber

When i try to compile play 2.5 with one module and sbt, compilation failed

My main project route file called "routes" include the module route file like this :

```
->      /foomodule                   foomodule.Routes
```

My **build.sbt** file :

```
lazy val foomodule= (project in file("modules/foomodule"))
.enablePlugins(PlayJava)


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
 .aggregate(foomodule)
 .dependsOn(foomodule)
```

Then i run sbt compilation with command :

```
sbt clean compile
```

I have this following error :

```
[error] /builds/foomainproject/conf/routes:5: not found: value foomodule
```

Answer (score 0):

in foomodule/conf, u should rename *routes* to ***foomodule.Routes***

have a look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Project-structure)